# Migrating from whatsApp Template to Content Builder

Tags: twilio, whatsapp, twilio-api, twilio-programmable-chat

I am migrating Twilio's `WhatsApp template` to their `Content Builder`, and after moving all the templates to the Content Template. I am not able to receive the Call to Action buttons.

For example, This is my content

template ID: `HX5fc0f957dc40af96ce9ef7055a2c7b22` with the following template details

```
You entered: {{1}}

Do you confirm?
```

and body:

```
You entered: 789660****3871

Do you confirm?`
```

I am using the following code after following this [doc](https://www.twilio.com/docs/content/send-templates-created-with-the-content-template-builder#new-content-fields-used-to-send-messages)

```
await twilioClient.messages.create({
  contentSid: "HX5fc0f957dc40af96ce9ef7055a2c7b22",
  body: messageBody,
  from: TWILIO_PHONE_NUMBER,
  contentVariables: JSON.stringify({
    1: '789660****3871'
  }),
  to: to,
});
```

In the logs, I am seeing: `## Warning - 12200 ### Schema validation warning The provided XML does not conform to the Twilio Markup XML schema. Please refer to the specific error and correct the problem.`

I am not able to understand what I am doing wrong here. I am aalso sending the `contentSid` and `contentVariables` both of which were not required previously.

Any hint or possible solution to work around?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you may be facing difficulties due to misunderstandings about the Content API's capabilities. Notably, the Content API does not support a `body` parameter.

This could be the cause for not being able to send the message. Also note that you [**need to specify a messaging service**](https://www.twilio.com/docs/content/create-and-send-your-first-content-api-template)  as a sender (see section "Before Starting") when using the Content API.

```js
await twilioClient.messages.create({
  contentSid: "HX5fc0f957dc40af96ce9ef7055a2c7b22",
  from: TWILIO_MESSAGING_SERVICE_SID,
  contentVariables: JSON.stringify({
    1: '789660****3871'
  }),
  to: to,
});
```

Also, it would be worth verifying the nature of the content template you've chosen - specifically, does it inherently incorporate a Call to Action button as per your requirements?
[image: Content Editor]

Comment: Hi @IObert I tried removing the body but again got this issue : `[Error]: A text message body or media urls must be specified.`. Body is: `await twilioClient.messages.create({
      contentSid: "HX5fc0f957dc40af96ce9ef7055a2c7b22",
      from: TWILIO_PHONE_NUMBER,
      contentVariables: JSON.stringify({
        1: '789660****3871'
      }),
      to: to,
    });`

Comment: where as my `whatsapp:+3200000000`

Comment: It's taking as SMS, I guess not treating as whatsApp message

Comment: Ah! i tried to send it using message service and it worked for me. Thanks for the help